# obtain desired output from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I had tried to use subprocess to execute vsftpd.

```
>>> subprocess.call(['vsftpd -v'], shell=True)
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
0
>>> subprocess.check_output(['vsftpd -v'], shell=True)
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
''
>>> version = subprocess.check_output(['vsftpd -v'], shell=True)
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
>>> version
''
>>>
```

You can see the issue that output of 'vsftpd -v' contains "zero character" at the end. When I want to store the output of subprocess.check_output it would be empty string.
So, what approach to obtain the right output(vsftpd: version 3.0.2)?

Comment: The output of that command goes to stderr rather than stdout, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to capture its output: `subprocess.check_output('vsftpd -v', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`.

Comment: Why are you calling with shell=True?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, it seem does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the version info is being printed in your REPL. I believe that means it is being written to stderr, not stdout. If it were going to stdout, it would be captured in `version` and not displayed (at least that's how the REPL works on my box).

Try this instead:

```
version = subprocess.check_output(
    'vsftpd -v',                 # Use string, not list, when shell = True.
    shell = True,
    stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,  # Capture both stdout and stderr.
)
```

Comment: it seem does not work for me. Sorry for my stupid, but value of version now is 'vsftpd: version 3.0.2'?